# ASP.NET MVC Routing: Multiple parameter in URL

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm trying to port a webservice from PHP to ASP.NET MVC.  Which, of course, means I have to duplicate the existing API.

Presently, a call, in it's canonical form would be like:

http://example.com/book/search?title=hamlet&author=shakes

However, it also accepts an alternate form:

http://example.com/book/search/title/hamlet/author/shakes

There are about five different search criteria, all optional, and they can be given in any order.

How does one do that in ASP.NET MVC Routing?

Comment: Sorry about posting a duplicate.  I searched under "routing" and forgot to check "route"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this.

```
[Route("Book/search/{*criteria}")]
public ActionResult Search(string criteria)
{
    var knownCriterias = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        {"author", ""},
        {"title",""},
        {"type",""}
    };
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(criteria))
    {

        var criteriaArr = criteria.Split('/');
        for (var index = 0; index < criteriaArr.Length; index++)
        {

            var criteriaItem = criteriaArr[index];
            if (knownCriterias.ContainsKey(criteriaItem))
            {
                if (criteriaArr.Length > (index + 1))
                    knownCriterias[criteriaItem] = criteriaArr[index + 1];
            }
        }
    }
    // Use knownCriterias dictionary now.
    return Content("Should return the search result here :)");
}
```

The last parameter prefixed with `*` is like a **catch-all** parameter which will store anything in the url after Book/search.

So when you request `yoursite.com/book/search/title/nice/author/jim` , the default model binder will map the value "title/nice/author/jim" to the criteria parameter. You can call the `Split` method on that string to get an array of url segments. Then convert the values to a dictionary and use that for your search code.

Basically the above code will read from the spilled array and set the value of `knownCriteria` dictionary items based on what you pass in your url.